# How to remove specific element from collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have declared a specific collecion looking like this

```
private static String[] testCollection= new String[]
        {"DB085175AF684343888344561C2723C1",
         "DB085175AF684343888344561C2723C2"}
```

Then there is a method that returns a random element from my collection.

```
public static <T> T getRandomElement(Collection<T> collection)
{
    int size = collection.size();
    return (T) collection.toArray()[random.nextInt(size)];
}
```

So my question is how to remove randomly chosen element when i declare it like

```
String testName = CollectionUtil.getRandomElement(informationSystemName);
```

I can't figure out how to build a method that removes generated **testName** from **testCollection**

Comment: It depends on the type of the Collection. If it's an ordered collection, such as List, you can remove the element at the i'th position. If it's not ordered, you can't. On the other hand, you can always remove the element by its value, so if it's a Set (which has no duplicate values), you can remove your randomly selected element this way. I'm not sure, however, there's a general solution for an arbitrary Collection.

Comment: See [Collection#remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in Java have a fixed size, which is set when the array is created. You cannot remove an element from an existing array such as `testCollection` - you'll have to create a new array without the element that you want to remove.

This is easier if you first convert the array to a `List`, use the `remove()` method of `List` to remove the desired element, and then create a new array from the list with the element removed:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(testCollection));
list.remove(testName);
    
String[] result = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Or work with `List` directly instead of arrays - collection classes such as `List` are more flexible and often more useful than arrays:

```
private static List<String> testCollection = List.of(
    "DB085175AF684343888344561C2723C1", "DB085175AF684343888344561C2723C2");

public static <T> T getRandomElement(List<T> collection) {
    int size = collection.size();
    return collection.get(random.nextInt(size));
}

String testName = getRandomElement(testCollection);
testCollection.remove(testName);
```

Comment: It appear the OP wanted to work with an arbitrary Collection (not with arrays and not with Lists - the array in the question is only used to randomly select an element from the Collection).

Comment: i guess using List is easier than working with arbitrary collections

Comment: It’s worth considering the actually intended operation first, i.e. when the indented operation is to remove a random element `return list.remove(random.nextInt(list.size()));` eliminates the need to perform a linear search for the element. And, since I see the `toArray(new String[list.size()])` idiom here, worth reading: [Arrays of Wisdom of the Ancients](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/). In short, `toArray(new String[0])` is not only simpler and less error prone, it turned out to be more efficient in practice.